# MongoDb. C# driver. Cannot register System.Type.Serializer.

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I need to store data with System.Type field, using mongosharp driver 2.1. Here [Storing System.Type with MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930443/storing-system-type-with-mongodb) I have read, that I need to make custom type serializer. I wrote one, but I cannot register this serializer. When I am calling  ***BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(Type), typeSerializer);***  Bson.Driver throwing exception that the serializer for System.Type is already registered. It is some default serializer. But it does not work. Thats why I have two questions:

1. If mongosharp driver has default serializer, why does not it working?
2. How can I replace default Serializer?